# Find the pdf $f_{y}(y)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given X is a random variable with pdf $f_X(x) = \frac{2x}{81} $ where $x \in (0,9)$. $Y = X^{2} - 8X$. My attempt is to find the pdf for $Y$ $f_Y(y)$.

I found that: $f_Y(y) = \frac{8}{81\sqrt{y+16}}$ where $y \in (-72, 81)$ by change of variables formula. (Some steps I use: $dy/dx = 2x - 8$ and the inverse $x = \pm \sqrt{y+16}  + 4$ ). But when I check the integral of $f_Y(y)$ under the region $(-72,81)$. The integral is  not equal to 1 as expected.

Comment: You need $y > -16$ to make $y+16 >0$.

Comment: So, the range of $Y$ is $(-16,81)$

Comment: To find the possible values of $Y$, we look at the range of the function $y=x^2-8x$ with a domain of $(0,9)$. Using a graph it's quick to tell that the range is $(-16,9)$ but we have many values of $Y$ that have two $X$'s corresponding to it, and under this circumstance it makes finding the PDF a lot harder

Comment: Check out [this Penn State Online Lecture about how to find the PDF when given a Two to One function](https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/158/)

Comment: I follow the step in the document you provided: But I check $\int_{-16}^{9} \frac{8}{81 \sqrt{y + 16}} dy = 80/81 \neq 1$.